# Streambuilder with ListView showing same data each tile?

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to use StreamBuilder to build out a ListView, but it is showing one item in each row of the ListView. I am using StreamBuilder broadcast. I use add(data).

```
child: StreamBuilder<GoogleAddress>(
                        stream: pickupStreamController.stream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) => ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: 8,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            print('Render $index');
                            if (snapshot.data != null) {
                              print("${snapshot.data.address}");
                              return _createListItem(
                                  icon: Icons.location_on,
                                  googleplace: snapshot.data,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    print("${snapshot.data.address}");
                                  });
                            } else {}
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

Here is the StreamController code where I add to the stream. It is adding different GoogleAddress data on each iteration.

```
GoogleAddress addy = GoogleAddress.fromJsonMap(map);
    if (sc != null) {
      sc.add(addy);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StreamBuilder` will use the **latest** value from the stream. To pass a list to `StreamBuilder` you would need to pass a list to `add`.

Which means to grow a list over time, you have to keep a regular list and pass it to `add` after modifying it.

```dart
final addresses = [];

GoogleAddress addy = GoogleAddress.fromJsonMap(map);

addresses.add(addy);
controller.add(addresses);
```